# how can i change the following cs into one CSS CLASS

Tags: css, linkbutton

```
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

### source

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_advanced

### reason

- i  would like to apply the above styles to a link button, was id changes by browsers wish(which is kind of a requirement so cannot keep selection on "id" on link button

  - so can i convert the above to a css class and then assign it to a link button, keeping intact the visited hover active styles?

### Real Reason

- The ul-li-linkbutton (navigation bar structure) to the left must change according to the css styling
- the ul-li-linkbutton to the top placed must not.

how to make this possible?

Comment: What is a link button? Links are typically `<a>` tags, whereas buttons are typically `<input>` or `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above, you are applying different styles to different elements. The only way you can combine classes is if you apply all styles to all elements. If you need to mix and match, you must have separate classes.

Although, you could move *most* of your a:link,a:visited rules into the ul class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul id="one_ul">
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
        onclick="LEFT_LINKBUTTON_CLICKED" CssClass="on_li">Products</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>

        <li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
        onclick="LEFT_LINKBUTTON_CLICKED" CssClass="on_li">Upload a File</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
body {
}

#one_ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

.on_li:link, .on_li:visited
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
width:120px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

.on_li:hover, .on_li:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```